# Is the ability to inject arbitrary CSS styles in an img tag a security vulnerability?

Tags: xss, vulnerability

I've discovered a behavior in a popular service's markdown parser that allows the 'style' attribute to be used within 'img' tags through some crafted markdown code. This allows for the application of arbitrary CSS styles to the image, leading to various forms of visual manipulation on the rendered page.

Furthermore, by using some high-performance-consuming CSS properties, it seems possible to cause a Denial of Service (DoS) on the browser of any person who views this rendered content.

I've reported this to the service and they've fixed it, but I'm curious to know if this is considered a security vulnerability. Could this be classified as a type of Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability? I'd appreciate any insights or clarifications.

Edit: I should clarify that this was not an expected behavior and was only reproducible under specific circumstances. The markdown parser typically restricts the use of certain attributes for security reasons, but I found that under certain conditions, these restrictions could be bypassed.

Comment: Yes, this is CSS injection. It's usually low-impact. If you get CSS injection on a text input, there is a cool technique using a web font to make it a key logger!